# Search Commerce Products by Tags

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, search

this is my first Craft CMS & Commerce build and I need some help with searching products by a tag field.

I have a tag field ("designTag") for each product and I would like to have a search bar that will only query the tag field for a specific product type ("designMedia") and return those products with matching or similar tag titles and also account for pagination. I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

**SEARCH FORM CODE:**

```
<form action="{{ url('design/keywords') }}">
    <label>Search By Keywords</label>
    <div class="append-icon">
        <input type="search" name="q" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter Keyword...">
        <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="nc-icon-outline ui-1_zoom"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**RESULTS CODE:**

```
{% set tagTitle = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set tag = craft.tags.title(tagTitle) %}    
{% set product = craft.commerce.products.search(query).order('score') %}

{% if product|length %}

{% paginate craft.commerce.products.type('designMedia').limit(48) as mediaProducts %}

{% for product in mediaProducts %}    
       <div class="item">
          <div class="item-wrapper">
            <figure class="he-3 cyan">
              <img src="{{ product.presentationSlides.first().getUrl('mediaDetail') }}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
              <div class="hover-icons">
                <div class="hover-icons-wrapper">
                  <a href="{{ product.presentationSlides.first().getUrl('mediaLightbox') }}" class="magnific hidden-xs-down">
                    <i class="nc-icon-outline ui-1_zoom"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="{{ product.url }}">
                    <i class="nc-icon-outline ui-2_link-71"></i>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#" class="hidden-xs-down">
                    <i class="nc-icon-outline ui-2_favourite-28"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No Results</p>  
{% endif %}

/*pagination code */
{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found that using the paginate tag would return all entries regardless of the keyword. I was able to get it to work by using the below results code. *(pagination still worked without the use of the pagination tag)*

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}

{% set tag = craft.tags.title(query).first() %}

{% set products = craft.commerce.products.search(query).limit(48) %}
{% if products|length %}
{% for product in products %}
   <div class="item">
      <div class="item-wrapper">
        <figure class="he-3 cyan">
          <img src="{{ product.presentationSlides.first().getUrl('mediaDetail') }}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
          <div class="hover-icons">
            <div class="hover-icons-wrapper">
              <a href="{{ product.presentationSlides.first().getUrl('mediaLightbox') }}" class="magnific hidden-xs-down">
                <i class="nc-icon-outline ui-1_zoom"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="{{ product.url }}">
                <i class="nc-icon-outline ui-2_link-71"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="hidden-xs-down">
                <i class="nc-icon-outline ui-2_favourite-28"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
   <p>No Results</p>  
{% endif %}

/*pagination code */
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work (set the limit to whatever you want/need):

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.title(tagTitle).first() %}    

{% paginate craft.commerce.products.relatedTo(tag).limit(10) as pageInfo, products %}

    {% for product in products %}

        {{ product.title }} etc

    {% endfor %}

    {% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
    {% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
```

For more on the pagination side of things, see: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate